# How to parse parameters from other functions to useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have the problem, that in a function in a functional component the state of an variable is changed via the useState hook method, but I also need to change other values, after this change was made. I read that the useEffect is usefull for changing other things, after a dependency was changed, but my problem is, that these values, that have to be parsed to an other variable a local. Now my question is how to parse this local variables to a useEffect function in order to assign it to an other state.

The setState method I am talking about is called in my handleChange method and my useEffect I am talking about is that with the parameter search

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {Container, Card, Button, Alert, CardGroup, CardDeck, FormControl, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
import reactDom from 'react-dom';
import { isCompositeComponentWithType } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import testpicture from '../imgs/maxresdefault.jpg';

function Movies( {moviesCall}) {


    const[arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const[arrTitle, setArrTitle] = useState([]);
    const[renderedOutput, setRenderedOutput] = useState([]);
    const lastsearch = useRef({succeed: true, value: ''});

    //API Call
    useEffect(() => {
       moviesCall.then((movies) => {
                setArr(movies.map((item) => {
                    return [item.title, item.description];
                    }));
             });         
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      setArrTitle(arr);
    }, [arr]);

    useEffect((search) => {
      console.log("Suche: " + search);
      if(search===undefined) lastsearch.current.lasttext='';
      else lastsearch.current.lasttext = search;
        if(arrTitle.length >0) {
          lastsearch.current.succeed = true;
          progress2();
        } else lastsearch.current.succeed = false;
    }, [arrTitle]);

   function progress2()  {
    let rows = [];
    let movies = arrTitle;
    for(let i=0; i<arrTitle.length; i+=3) {
      rows.push(movies.slice(i, i+3));
    }
  //  console.log(rows);

    setRenderedOutput(rows.map((item) => {
      return(<CardDeck>
        {item.map((item2, index) => {
          return (
          <Card> 
            <img src={testpicture}></img>
               <Card.Body>
           <Card.Title>{item2[0]}</Card.Title>
           <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">Card Subtitle</Card.Subtitle>
          <Card.Text>
           {item2[1]}  
           </Card.Text>
           <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
           <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link>
         </Card.Body>
      </Card>);
        })}
      </CardDeck>);
    }));
    }


    const handleChange = ((event) => {
      // console.log("Succeed" + lastsearch.current.succeed);
      // console.log("Text: " + lastsearch.current.lasttext);
      // console.log("Object: " + lastsearch.current);
        let search = (event.target.value).trim();
        let length = search.length;
        let last = lastsearch.current;
        // console.log("Last: " + last);
        let lastsearchtext = (last.lasttext).trim();
       if(!length==0 && (lastsearchtext === '' || !(lastsearchtext.length <= length && search.substring(0, lastsearchtext.length).toUpperCase() === lastsearchtext.toUpperCase() && last.current.succeed === false))) {
         console.log("Aufruf***********************************************************************************************************************************************");
         setArrTitle(arr.filter((item, index) => {
           let temp = item[0];
            if(!temp.length<length && search.toUpperCase() === temp.trim().substring(0, length).toUpperCase()) {
              return item;
            }
        }));
      } else if(length==0) {
        setArrTitle(arr);
      }
    });

    return(
        <><Form.Control type="input" placeholder="Search for a specific movie" onChange={handleChange}/>
       <div>{renderedOutput} </div>
      </>
    );
}

export default Movies;
´´´
```